# QuickFix pip install

Tags: python, quickfix

I am using the latest python 3.
I would like to pip install quickfix (http://www.quickfixengine.org/).
But I get an error. (SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print')
Please tell me how to install.
Best regards.

Comment: Did you try adding a parenthesis in whatever print statement is failing?  Is it an installer error?  Is there specific code you're updating that might be from python 2 where parenthesis might not have been needed?  What OS are you on?

Comment: Going by https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/issues/125, QuickFIX does not work in Python 3. People have been asking for a 3-compatible version since at least 2014.

Comment: J0hn, Kevin Thank you for your comment.
My OS is Windows 10pro.
QuickFix does not work with python 3!

Answer (score 2):

That error is given when you are attempting to install a package which has not been upgraded for a python 2.x version (Python 2.x does not use parenthesis for the print function, whereas in 3.x the parenthesis are required syntax). Because of this you will not be able to install the package as is in python 3.x.

You could either contact the creator asking for them to upgrade their package or you could download the source code itself and make the required fixes to that code.

Comment: Thank you for answering!

I understand.
Download quickfix from github and modify the code.
thank you very much.